# How can I render a particular Threejs Object3D with an off-center perspective?

Tags: javascript, three.js, perspective, perspectivecamera

I have a complex scene where a text should be drawn on top of the page. I also have an effect that causes the text to rotate towards the viewer on mouse-hover. This effect looks very good when the text is in the middle of the screen, but when it's on top of the page, the perspective distortion causes it to look not the way I want.

In essence, I want to draw that object in the same place, but with the perspective center shifted. I know about the camera offset, but that doesn't help since it impacts the entire camera/scene and not a single object.

Comment: Can you show us in a snippet what you've tried? Not sure what you mean by 'perspective center shifted', so it would help to see what you have now and the behavior you're expecting.

Comment: @Marquizzo A perspective projection matrix generated by default looks straight down the Z axis. The model matrices of elements then move them around the frustum. What I want is to have the perspective for a few elements behave as if they were on that center line and not off-axis.